# How do I import configurable products in Magento?

Tags: magento, csv, import, dataflow, configurable

I’m making a clothing webshop and need to create configurable products in the import process, to link the sizes together.

The import process is working perfectly and both the simple products and the configurable product is created as hoped.

My problem however, is that the simple products doesn’t seem to link together with the configurable product as “associated products”

I’m importing a CSV with 2 products. Each product has 5 sizes = 12 products (10 simple, 2 configurable) - See here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avt7PlGLhoRvdEhkMDR5X1FyYVgtVGhsdVlMZXdmMVE

I tried adding the columns:
“associated” = SKUs seperated by comma
and
“config_attributes” = Size (the configurable attribute for the associated simple products)

But they still aren’t linking together - what am I doing wrong?

For the record I am using Magento Community 1.7.

Comment: try reindex and clear cache

Comment: how did you prepare your csv file, when you export the file magento by its inherent bug puts some fields with no values. if you try to import it again it may not work. for example field like 'stock' & etc. Check these values. 

if nothing works, there (following)(http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6941/P60/#t66862) would help you.